# Open gallery related to ID from database inside lightbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a small problem here, i'm trying to have an anchor tag called "Photos", so when the user clicks on that anchor, tha Ajax will grab the results from PHP/MySQL database and display the images inside the opened lightbox.

I have tried to create something like this:

```
<a href="" data-lightbox="imoveis">Fotos</a>
```

Then Ajax:

```
 $(document).on('click','#photos',function(event){

    var imovel_id = $(this).attr('id');


    $.ajax({
      url: 'gallery_query',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType:"json",
      data:{imovel_id: imovel_id},
      success: function(data) {
            if(data.status == 1) {
                //Display images;
            } else {
                // Return Error message;
            }
        }
    });
    initLightbox();
});
```

Then my PHP query:

```
<?php require("includes/db_connect.php"); ?>
<?php $imovel_id = $_POST['property_id']; ?>

<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE imovel_id = '$imovel_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){
?> 
<?php 

if($result > 0){

    $data['status'] = 1;
    $data['retorno'] .= '<a href="../images/imoveis/'. $row['foto_gallery'] .'" data-lightbox="imoveis"><img src="../images/imoveis/'. $row['foto_gallery'] .'></a>';
    mysqli_close($connection);
}else{
    $data['status'] = 0;
    $data['retorno'] = "Erro ao exibir fotos, se o erro persistir, entre em contato conosco.";
}
echo json_encode($data);

?>
<?php } ?>
```

My problem is, i don't know if this is working, and what to use in Ajax success. I'm learning how Ajax works exactly, so i tried to implement it with lightbox as experiment.
Any thoughs?

Thanks!

Comment: Monitor the request in the network tab of your developer console. See where/if it hangs and/or what the response is. You don't need to open and close the PHP as much as you are (just open it at the start, don't even need to close, http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php). Your code is open to SQL injections. You won't get into the fetch if there aren't results so you dont need the `if($result > 0){`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i've changed my code here, like, i don't have problems retrieving the content with ajax, my only problem is, how can i attach the results into the lightbox? do i need to attach to any element inside it or create something dynamically?

Comment: @chris85, you're right, my bad, i was translating as i'm from Brazil, so i tried to translate something for understanding

Comment: If wana keep banging your head with lightbox, up to you but the way you are trying to do, i highly suggest do it with bootstrap modal, it will do all the dirty work for you, no ajax calls, no need to attach results into lightbox, simple add bootstrap library, paste modal html in the page from where you are calling the request and set href link of php file with id, thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few pointers:

Escape your string to ensure no SQL injections are sent to your server (not escaping could allow someone to delete all your data!

```
<?php $imovel_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['property_id']); ?>
```

This is if in your database you record strings for imovel_id,

If not

```
<?php $imovel_id = intval($_POST['property_id']); ?>
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE imovel_id = $imovel_id";
```

Sending the result:

```
// declare $data before, scope issue
$data = null;
if($result > 0){

    $data['status'] = 1;
    $data['retorno'] .= '<a href="../images/imoveis/'. $row['foto_gallery'] .'" data-lightbox="imoveis"><img src="../images/imoveis/'. $row['foto_gallery'] .'"></a>'; // you were missing a closing quote for the image src.
}else{
    $data['status'] = 0;
    $data['retorno'] = "Erro ao exibir fotos, se o erro persistir, entre em contato conosco.";
}
mysqli_close($connection); // close connection regardless of returned data
echo json_encode($data);
```

Hope this helps.

Edit:

One last thing, if you want to display what you are receiving:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'gallery_query',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType:"json",
  data:{imovel_id: imovel_id},
  success: function(data) {
        if(data.status == 1) {
            $('#idOfElement').html(data.retorno);
        } else {
            // Return Error message;
        }
    }
});
```